# Upgrade Apache 2.22 to a version that supports ECDHE

Tags: server, apache2, security

I'm trying to setup my Ubuntu 12.04 server installation to support perfect forward security.  It seems that the default Apache 2.2.22 build does not support ECDHE.  Any suggestions on a good way to upgrade to a compatible version of Apache?

Comment: related posts: http://askubuntu.com/q/336193/62483 http://askubuntu.com/q/213695/62483